# Convert MySQL view back into a query

Tags: mysql, view

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere but I haven't been able to find the answer.

I created a view using HeidiSQL from a query I made.  Due to a power outage my query was lost but the view was saved.  Is there any way to convert the view back into a query?  It is very ugly and hard to edit as a view.

The VIEW:

```
SELECT `c`.`assettag` AS `c_assetTag`, 
       `c`.`serialnumber` AS `c_serialNumber`, 
       `c`.`datepurchased` AS `c_datePurchased`,`c`.`status` AS `c_status`, 
       `c`.`dateretired` AS `c_dateRetired`,`c`.`loaner` AS `c_loaner`, 
       `c`.`school` AS `c_school`,`c`.`mac` AS `c_mac`, 
       `c`.`notes` AS `c_notes`, 
       `c`.`model` AS `c_model`,`c`.`location` AS `c_location`, 
       `c`.`lastlocationupdate` AS `c_lastLocationUpdate`, 
       `c`.`warrantyexpiration` AS `c_warrantyExpiration`, 
       `c`.`warrantyvoid` AS `c_warrantyVoid`, 
       `c`.`warrantyvoidnotes` AS `c_warrantyVoidNotes`, 
       `c`.`description` AS `c_description`, 
       `a`.`assignmentid` AS `a_assignmentID`, 
       `a`.`studentid` AS `a_studentID`,`a`.`grade` AS `a_grade`, 
       `a`.`gradyear` AS `a_gradYear`,`a`.`assettag` AS `a_assetTag`, 
       `a`.`issuedate` AS `a_issueDate`,`a`.`returndate` AS `a_returnDate`, 
       `a`.`school` AS `a_school`,`a`.`issuer` AS `a_issuer`, 
       `a`.`repossessor` AS `a_repossessor`,`a`.`loaner` AS `a_loaner`, 
       `a`.`backpack` AS `a_backpack`,`a`.`duckhead` AS `a_duckhead`, 
       `a`.`charger` AS `a_charger`,`a`.`laptop` AS `a_laptop`, 
       `a`.`user` AS `a_user`, 
       `s`.`uname` AS `s_uName`,`s`.`fname` AS `s_fName`, 
       `s`.`lname` AS `s_lName`,`s`.`test` AS `s_test`, 
       `s`.`studentid` AS `s_studentID`,`s`.`gradyear` AS `s_gradYear`, 
       `s`.`active` AS `s_active`,`s`.`grade` AS `s_grade`, 
       `s`.`tblgrade` AS `s_tblGrade`,`s`.`password` AS `s_password`, 
       `s`.`school` AS `s_school`,`s`.`mail` AS `s_mail`, 
       `s`.`lunch` AS `s_lunch`, 
       `s`.`dayuser` AS `s_dayuser`, 
       `la_laptop`.`timestamp` AS `LaptopReturnDate`, 
              ( ( ( ( `la_laptop`.`timestamp` - `a`.`issuedate` ) / 60 ) / 
                  60 ) / 24 ) AS `LaptopAssignmentLength`, 
       `la_backpack`.`timestamp` AS `BackpackReturnDate`, 
       `la_charger`.`timestamp` AS `ChargerReturnDate`, 
       `la_duckhead`.`timestamp` AS `DuckheadReturnDate` 
FROM   (((((((((((`computer` `c` 
                  LEFT JOIN `assignment` `a` 
                         ON(( `a`.`assettag` = `c`.`assettag` ))) 
                 LEFT JOIN `assignment` `a2` 
                        ON(( ( `c`.`assettag` = `a2`.`assettag` ) 
                             AND ( ( `a`.`issuedate` < `a2`.`issuedate` ) 
                                    OR ( ( `a`.`issuedate` = 
                                           `a2`.`issuedate` ) 
                                         AND ( `a`.`assignmentid` < 
                                 `a2`.`assignmentid` ) ) ) ))) 
                LEFT JOIN `log_assignment` `la_laptop` 
                       ON(( ( `la_laptop`.`assignmentid` = 
                              `a`.`assignmentid` ) 
                            AND ( `la_laptop`.`laptop` = 1 ) ))) 
               LEFT JOIN `log_assignment` `la_laptop2` 
                      ON(( ( `a`.`assignmentid` = 
                             `la_laptop2`.`assignmentid` ) 
                           AND ( ( `la_laptop`.`timestamp` < 
                                 `la_laptop2`.`timestamp` ) 
                                  OR ( ( `la_laptop`.`timestamp` = 
                                         `la_laptop2`.`timestamp` ) 
                                       AND ( `la_laptop`.`logid` < 
                               `la_laptop`.`logid` ) ) ) ))) 
              LEFT JOIN `log_assignment` `la_backpack` 
                     ON(( ( `la_backpack`.`assignmentid` = 
                            `a`.`assignmentid` ) 
                          AND ( `la_backpack`.`backpack` = 1 ) ))) 
             LEFT JOIN `log_assignment` `la_backpack2` 
                    ON(( ( `a`.`assignmentid` = 
                           `la_backpack2`.`assignmentid` ) 
                         AND ( ( `la_backpack`.`timestamp` < 
                               `la_backpack2`.`timestamp` ) 
                                OR ( ( `la_backpack`.`timestamp` = 
                                       `la_backpack2`.`timestamp` ) 
                                     AND ( `la_backpack`.`logid` < 
                                         `la_backpack`.`logid` ) ) ) ))) 
            LEFT JOIN `log_assignment` `la_charger` 
                   ON(( ( `la_charger`.`assignmentid` = 
                        `a`.`assignmentid` ) 
                        AND ( `la_charger`.`charger` = 1 ) ))) 
           LEFT JOIN `log_assignment` `la_charger2` 
                  ON(( ( `a`.`assignmentid` = 
                       `la_charger2`.`assignmentid` ) 
                       AND ( ( `la_charger`.`timestamp` < 
                             `la_charger2`.`timestamp` ) 
                              OR ( ( `la_charger`.`timestamp` = 
                                     `la_charger2`.`timestamp` ) 
                                   AND ( `la_charger`.`logid` < 
                                 `la_charger`.`logid` ) ) ) ))) 
          LEFT JOIN `log_assignment` `la_duckhead` 
                 ON(( ( `la_duckhead`.`assignmentid` = `a`.`assignmentid` ) 
                      AND ( `la_duckhead`.`duckhead` = 1 ) ))) 
         LEFT JOIN `log_assignment` `la_duckhead2` 
                ON(( ( `a`.`assignmentid` = `la_duckhead2`.`assignmentid` ) 
                     AND ( ( `la_duckhead`.`timestamp` < 
                           `la_duckhead2`.`timestamp` ) 
                            OR ( ( `la_duckhead`.`timestamp` = 
                                   `la_duckhead2`.`timestamp` ) 
                                 AND ( `la_duckhead`.`logid` < 
                                     `la_duckhead`.`logid` ) ) ) ))) 
        LEFT JOIN `student` `s` 
               ON(( `s`.`studentid` = `a`.`studentid` ))) 
WHERE  ( ( 1 = 1 ) 
         AND isnull(`a2`.`assignmentid`) 
         AND isnull(`la_laptop2`.`logid`) 
         AND isnull(`la_backpack2`.`logid`) 
         AND isnull(`la_charger2`.`logid`) 
         AND isnull(`la_duckhead2`.`logid`) )
```

Comment: A view is just a query with added `CREATE VIEW blah as SELECT...`

Comment: You can just remove the "CREATE VIEW" as that's the syntax to create a view.

Comment: My editor puts the view all on one line.  When I looked at the query and saw a million parentheses I thought it was completely different.  It is very different from the original query I wrote but now that someone formatted it with new lines it looks like it really is just the query with formatting changes.  No wonder I couldn't find the answer - the question was invalid :-)  Thanks